# Unable to access interface android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, interface

I am trying to access interface from other module in android studio where my project structure looks like this

```
projectRoot-folder

 app-main-module //this is main app which i run
    com.mypackage.files
      MyClass.java
    build.gradle

 other-library-module //this is library module which i added
    com.package.files
      InterfaceFile.java
    build.gradle

 build.gradle
 settings.gradle
```

I am implementing interface for MyClass.java and that is working fine with no compile errors,but when i press run it is giving the following error's can anyone explain why it is so?, any help is appreciated thank you.

```
Error:(5, 32) error: cannot find symbol class InterfaceFile
Error:(10, 52) error: cannot find symbol class InterfaceFile
Error:(11, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(16, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: You've got to declare the other module as library and add it as a library to your app module

Comment: @Little i already did

Answer (score 0):

**You have to add in your file settings.gradle this lines:**

```
include ':module2'
project(':module2').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../Project 2/Module2')
```

Then you have to add in your builde.gradle (Module: app) in the dependencies tree, this line:

```
compile project(':module2')
```

or go into the Project Structure > app > Dependencies, click on Add, choose 3 Module Dependencies and select your module

Comment: i didn't understand the second parameter to the File can u explain?

Comment: which one u didn't understand? add compile project(':module2') in dependencies where you use to add libraries (example : compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1')

Comment: according to my question it should be
    project('other-module').projectDir=new File(settingsDir,':other-module') right?

Comment: or else you can do like File->new->Import Module->select your module project and add compile project(':project_name') in dependencies